# Need help to understanding floating point rounding presented in "Varieties of Static Analyzers: A Comparison with ASTREE"

Tags: c, floating-point

```
% cat double-float1.c

 int main () {
 double x; float a, y, z, r1, r2;
 a = 1.0; x = 1125899973951488.0; y = (x + a); z = (x - a);
 r1 = y - z; r2 = 2 * a;
 printf("(x + a) - (x - a) = %f\n", r1);
 printf("2a = %f\n", r2);
 }



% gcc double-float1.c >& /dev/null; ./a.out
 (x + a) - (x - a) = 134217728.000000
 2a = 2.000000
```

After changing the least significant digit

```
% cat double-float2.c



int main () {
 double x; float a, y, z, r1, r2;
 a = 1.0; x = 1125899973951487.0; y = (x + a); z = (x - a);
 r1 = y - z; r2 = 2 * a;
 printf("(x + a) - (x - a) = %f\n", r1);
 printf("2a = %f\n", r2);
 }



% gcc double-float2.c >& /dev/null; ./a.out
 (x + a) - (x - a) = 0.000000
 2a = 2.000000
```

Can anyone please help me to understand how internal representation in the first example is round to different values and round to same values in the second example. The link to the paper where I have found the above examples given below.

[Varieties of Static Analyzers: A Comparison with ASTREE](http://www.di.ens.fr/~cousot/publications.www/CousotP-Astree-TASE07.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the floating point numbers internally must be represented using a mantissa with a limited precision. First, if the actual decimal number you are storing can not be representable using an actual binary number, it is rounded to the next nearest binary value, according to certain [IEEE-754 rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules). Next, if the actual decimal number has more digits than the precision of the floating point type allows, it will have to be rounded, even if you are using a decimal floating point type.

Note that the underlying reason, in this case, is precision, not the binary format, although the binary format adds additional confusion because it's rounded to the nearest number representable with 24 binary digits. If your language had a native decimal floating point type with 10 digits of precision, it would still have to round numbers in memory:

```
Decimal number     | Nearest decimal with 10 digits precision 
------------------ | ---------------------------------------
123450000149997.0  | 123450000100000
123450000149998.0  | 123450000100000
123450000149999.0  | 123450000100000
123450000150000.0  | 123450000200000
123450000150001.0  | 123450000200000
123450000150002.0  | 123450000200000
```

In your case, the rounding point is exactly between `1125899973951488` and `1125899973951489`. Since a [32-bit float has 24 bits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (23 bits reserved for the mantissa + implicit leading bit set to 1), it can have an approximate decimal precision of ~7.22 decimal digits. This is how the numbers are stored in your example:

```
Decimal number     | Actual IEEE-754 value | IEEE-754 bits (sign, exponent, mantissa)
------------------ | ----------------------|-----------------------------------------
1125899973951486.0 | 1125899906842624      | 0 10110001 00000000000000000000000
1125899973951487.0 | 1125899906842624      | 0 10110001 00000000000000000000000
1125899973951488.0 | 1125899906842624      | 0 10110001 00000000000000000000000
1125899973951489.0 | 1125900041060352      | 0 10110001 00000000000000000000001
1125899973951490.0 | 1125900041060352      | 0 10110001 00000000000000000000001
1125899973951491.0 | 1125900041060352      | 0 10110001 00000000000000000000001
```

So `(x - 1)` and `(x + 1)` will round to the same value, until you reach `1125899973951488.0`. To explore how floats are stored internally using IEEE-754, there is a useful [online calculator](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) you can use.

Comment: @chux: thanks, I don't know where 22 came from, I've clarified both points I hope.

Answer (score -1):

Run this program - it will show you the trap of the float :)

```
float n = 0.0f;
uint32_t k;

while (1) 
{
    n += 1.0f; k++;

    if (k == 10000)
    {
        printf("%f\n", n);
        k = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: I ran the program. Couldn't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: eventually what did you get?

Comment: The output is indeed interesting. I see the value of `n` repeatedly. The value is stuck at a value even if the loop goes on. Why is this happening?

Comment: Float limitations. The "granulation" later is larger than 1.0

Comment: So the binary representation of the `float` can't store the precise value at some stage. Is that it? But if it is so, why is the value just freezing? At least the value should be erroneous right? `n` gets incremented by `1` during each iteration but after `16777216`, it is not affected by the `n+=1f;`.